# Alterar o valor de conteúdo de uma linha de um tableview javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Seguinte, estou utilizando o hsqldb para fazer um trabalho de faculdade, e necessito alterar o conteúdo da visualização de uma linha do tableview

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, nas colunas Nome do time, necessitaria em vez do código, o nome do time

O banco está montado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o controller está assim:

```
@FXML private Button btnSalvar;
  @FXML private TableView<Partida> tabela;
  @FXML private TableColumn<Partida, String> clmTime1;
  @FXML private TableColumn<Partida, Integer> clmPlacar1;
  @FXML private TableColumn<String, String> clmX;
  @FXML private TableColumn<Partida, Integer> clmPlacar2;
  @FXML private TableColumn<Partida, String> clmTime2;

  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      clmTime1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cod_time1"));
      clmPlacar1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gol_time1"));
      clmX.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(""));
      clmPlacar2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gol_time2"));
      clmTime2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cod_time2"));
      refreshTable();         
  }

  @FXML
  private void refreshTable() {
        ArrayList<Partida> listaPartida = new partidaDAO().listarPartidas();
        ObservableList<Partida> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaPartida);
        tabela.setItems(observableList);        
    }
```

como poderia realizar essa mudança?

Comment: Olá, insira o código na pergunta e não um print.

Comment: Opa, alterei aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode realizar um join entre as tabelas para mostrar os nomes ao invés dos códigos e repassar essa mudança para seu código. Vamos supor que sua tabela seja dessa forma ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1ccca/1)), então o select abaixo produz o resultado:

```
select t1.`nome`, `gols_time1`, t2.`nome`, `gols_time2` from partida
inner join `time` t1 on (`time1` = t1.`idtime`)
inner join `time` t2 on (`time2` = t2.`idtime`)
```

> Flamengo  0   Vasco   0

Seu problema é mais a sua consulta no banco do que um problema de JavaFX, pois seu código está correto. (Para receber um nome do tipo string)